# What does it mean to have "user was removed" on my account?

Tags: discussion, reputation, profile-page

Does that mean you are banned from the stack exchange site?

Answer (score 7):

No, it means that the user who upvoted your post had his account deleted.

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/user-was-removed

Comment: Most of the time this means the user deleted his own account, not that moderators or SE deleted the account.  (Fortunately WB doesn't get many spammers, which is the main source of mod-deleted accounts on other sites.)